# Angular ng-model formdata not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So this is my controller:

```
var expenses = angular.module('expenses', []);

expenses.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http){
$scope.formData = {};

$http.get('/api/transactions').then(function(data){
    $scope.transactions = data.data;
    console.log(data.data);
}, function(error){
    console.log(error)
});

$scope.createTransaction = function() {
    console.log($scope.formData)
    $http.post('/api/transactions', $scope.formData).then(function(data) {
        $scope.formData = {}; 
        $scope.transactions = data.data;
        console.log(data.data);
    }, function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
};
})
```

And this is my html:

```
<div id="mdlInputExpense" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Create a new expense</h4>
            <div class="row">
            <form class="col s12" ng-submit="createTransaction()">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input placeholder="Shop" id="shop" type="text" class="validate autocomplete" ng-model="formData.shop">
                        <label for="shop">Shop</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input placeholder="Category" id="category" type="text" class="validate autocomplete" ng-model="formData.category">
                        <label for="category">Category</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input placeholder="Amount of money" id="amount" type="number" class="validate" ng-model="formData.amount">
                    <label for="amount">Amount of money</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Submit</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Submit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click the submit button I expect formData to contain data which will be used to send to the server. Whenever I check the contents it just displays {}, so it doesn't contain any data.

I got ng-controller="mainController" on the body tag so that's not the issue.

**EDIT 1**

```
app.post('/api/transactions', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body)
Transaction.create({
    category : req.body.category,
    shop: req.body.shop,
    amount: req.body.amount,
    direction: 'String',
}, function(err, todo) {
    if (err){
        res.send(err);
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    Transaction.find(function(err, transactions) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(transactions);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Haven't you to create the $scope.formData  property's before bind the view?.

Comment: Show whats in `Network tab` in `Developer tools console` What request contains? Also to be sure its empty better log as `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.formData))` because developer tools update log in realtime

Comment: @Leguest in the networks tab I don't see the POST happening, only the GET afterwards.

Comment: Why there is GET afterwards? Where do you call a get request in your submit handler?

Comment: @Leguest after posting, I get result from the server and return them.

Comment: It seems your code is working, check out your API, I have created a https://jsfiddle.net/stL9gtxd/ by using your code but I have used a fake api, and I can see data going out to POST method. Check it out and let me know in case of any questions

Comment: @Knitesh So I went to your fiddle, opened network tab, entered some values and hit submit. In the request I only see {} without any data.

Comment: @GianiNoyez that's weird as I see data in my network tab ... What browser you are using ? I am on chrome v 58

Comment: @Knitesh, I'm starting to feel like it's a browser related issue. I'm using Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit) Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine, the eay I see it. Here is link to jsbin: http://jsbin.com/bafalawaje/edit?html,js,console,output
  //html
    
    
    
    
      
      
      JS Bin
    
    
      
            
                Create a new expense
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                            Shop
                        
                        
                            
                            Category
                        
                    
                    
                        
                        
                        Amount of money
                        
                    
                    Submit
                
            
            
            
                Submit

```
//js
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  console.log('created')
  $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.createTransaction = function(){
    console.log($scope.formData.shop);
  }
})
```